# Rails time_ago_in_words gives error undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is an individual post partial that is rendered as part of a feed partial. So its a partial within a partial.

Everything works fine except for the `time_ago_in_words` line. The error is

```
ActionView::Template::Error:
   undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass
```

It doesn't make sense because `feed_post` is not nil. its rendered 3 times before the error shows up. There is a `created_at` because the same posts are shown in a different view, so I know its in the database. Also, if I remove `time_ago_in_words` and just have `feed_post.created_at` it works fine. I'm stumped.

`# shared/_feed_post.html.erb`

```
  <li>
  <%= link_to gravatar(feed_post.user), feed_post.user %>
  <span class="user">
    <%= link_to feed_post.user.email, feed_post.user %>
  </span>
  <span class="post_text">
    <%= feed_post.text %>
  </span>
  <span class="timestamp">
    <%= time_ago_in_words(feed_post.created_at) %> #### Here is the trouble
  </span>
</li>
```

Here I render the partial with collection `@feed_posts`

`# shared/_feed.html.erb`

```
<% if @feed_posts.any? %>
  <ol class="posts">
    <%= render partial: 'shared/feed_post', collection: @feed_posts %>
  </ol>
<% end %>
```

And here is the controller action

```
def home
  @feed_posts = current_user.feed
end
```

Hopefully this is an easy error for someone to help with. I just don't see it. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

EDIT
Here is the full trace

```
app/views/shared/_feed_post.html.erb:10:in `_app_views_shared__feed_post_html_erb___559710345292053670_70357988998940'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_view/template.rb:141:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:399:in `block in collection_with_template'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:395:in `map'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:395:in `collection_with_template'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:291:in `render_collection'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:275:in `block in render'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:274:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:47:in `render_partial'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:21:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:24:in `render'
app/views/shared/_feed.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_shared__feed_html_erb__1326961751106757393_70357968045160'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_view/template.rb:141:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:306:in `render_partial'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:279:in `block in render'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:278:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:47:in `render_partial'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:27:in `render'
app/views/pages/home.html.erb:12:in `_app_views_pages_home_html_erb__4035833185189931772_70357967633720'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_view/template.rb:141:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:49:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:48:in `block in render_template'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:56:in `render_with_layout'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:47:in `render_template'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:17:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:127:in `_render_template'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:219:in `_render_template'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:120:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:33:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:26:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:97:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
/Users/Brian/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/benchmark.rb:296:in `realtime'
activesupport (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:403:in `_run__533002015063756194__process_action__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:655:in `call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:369:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__3615549091380738184__call__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.0.0.rc2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.0.0.rc2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
railties (4.0.0.rc2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.0.0.rc2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.0.rc2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
railties (4.0.0.rc2) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
railties (4.0.0.rc2) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
/Users/Brian/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/Users/Brian/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/Users/Brian/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: Are you sure all the feed_posts have created_at set? Looks like its null for one of them

Comment: yes because the posts that make up the feed are displayed on the users profile as well when they are created. `<%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %>` in the `posts/_post` partial shows up just fine on the profile page. That is what is strange.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
<li>
  <%= link_to gravatar(feed_post.user), feed_post.user %>
  <span class="user">
    <%= link_to feed_post.user.email, feed_post.user %>
  </span>
  <span class="post_text">
    <%= feed_post.text %>
  </span>
  <span class="timestamp">
    <%= time_ago_in_words(feed_post.created_at) unless feed_post.created_at.blank?%> #### Here is the trouble
  </span>
</li>
```

Comment: I would have bet you that wouldn't work, but it did work. Thanks. Now I'm not sure why. All posts have a created_at. In other words, none are blank. why does this make a difference.

Comment: If it works, atleast one of your feed_posts have created_at as nil or empty string. You keep saying 'all posts have a created_at'. do you mean posts or feed_posts?

Comment: Ok I'll look into it. It must be something. Thanks for your help

Comment: For Mongoid, if you have the identity map enabled and you do `current_user.posts.build` (for example to populate a blank form entry...), you may end up with the blank unsaved record still being present in the identity map for the user instance (current_user), and being returned with `current_user.posts`.

Comment: I looked at the db and all `created_at` fields are populated. I used a rake task to create the sample db. I don't use `build`, just `create!`. The post creation part is `def create_posts; users = User.all; 50.times do; users.each { |user| user.posts.create!(text: Faker::Lorem.paragraph) }; end; end; I wonder if this is part of the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same problem, then I found out that it was caused by a new_record object on the page. I tried to combine new action and index action on the same page. In your case, I suspect that you have @feed_posts=[parent_object].feed_posts and @feed_post=[parent_object].feed_posts.build in your feed_post controller.

Comment: This was my issue as well. Changing the controller from '@comment = @post.comments.build(comment_params)' to '@comment = Comment.new(comment_params)' and '@comment.post = @post' then allowed me to use time_ago_in_words in the view which has both new and index actions for comments.